# Fedora 18 host cannot ping Windows XP guest

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ip

I have my laptop running Fedora 18. I want to run a Windows XP guest using VirtualBox 4.2.6. My configuration seems correct, here
is my networking report.

Fedora 18 host

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 16436
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 72  bytes 6640 (6.4 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 72  bytes 6640 (6.4 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

p2p1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 00:1e:68:68:11:93  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 16  

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.231.243.74  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.20.31.30
    ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
    RX packets 36895  bytes 35633124 (33.9 MiB)
    RX errors 2  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 42421  bytes 3077319 (2.9 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vboxnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.56.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
    inet6 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 348  bytes 41858 (40.8 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

As for my XP guest, the IP address is 192.168.56.2. On the network setup I've choosen the host-only adapter with `vboxnet0`. Yet
when I perform a `ping` from my Fedora host, it doesn't yield any reply.

```
[root@laptop Downloads]# ping 192.168.56.2
PING 192.168.56.2 (192.168.56.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
 //here is should be reply answer from blablabla, like in most normal ping
```

`route -n` command on the Fedora 18 host result

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.20.31.7      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0
10.20.31.7      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet0
```

and also my guest windows xp `route print` commands yields

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
0x1 ........................... MS TCP Loopback interface
0x2 ...08 00 27 a5 72 21 ...... AMD PCNET Family PCI Ethernet Adapter - Packet Scheduler Miniport
===========================================================================
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
    127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1   1
  192.168.56.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.56.2    192.168.56.2      20
  192.168.56.2  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1      20
 192.168.56.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.56.2    192.168.56.2     20
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0     192.168.56.2    192.168.56.2   20
 255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.56.2    192.168.56.2    1
 ===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is there a firewall on the guest or on the host? What do you get when you ping the host from the guest? Post the output of `route -n` on the host and `route print` on the guest.

Comment: @Gilles, I've just made edited version of route -n result

Comment: @Gilles, I've just realized that newly freshed installed Fedora 18, just brought firewalld service instead of regular iptables, but from now googling on the net, on how to deactivate firewalld service, the problems still persist

Answer (score 1):

The subnet mask in xp should be 255.255.255.0 instead of 255.255.255.255

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the `firewalld` package fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Can the guest Windows XP machine ping the host? It's probably Windows Firewall in the way, try disabling that.

Comment: This post is not easily understandable, nor readily helpful. Please consider revising your answer to offer more helpful instructions or recommendations.